# Join multiple tables in yesod

Tags: database, haskell, yesod

Say I have the following models:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
Payment
    timestamp UTCTime
    from UserId
    to UserId
    receiptId ReceiptId
ReceiptUser                     
    userId UserId
    receiptId ReceiptId
Receipt
    owner UserId
    money Int
```

I want to perform a query like this:

```
SELECT ReceiptUser.UserId, Receipt.ReceiptOwner, Receipt.Id, Receipt.Price
FROM ReceiptUser, Receipt, Payment
WHERE ReceiptUser.ReceiptId == Receipt.Id
      AND NOT (Payment.ReceiptId == Receipt.Id AND Payment.From == ReceiptUser.UserId AND Payment.To == Receipt.Owner)
```

Which is supposed to find all users who have not yet payed another user, plus the corresponding receipt information.

How could I express this in yesod persistent? It seems to me persistent only provides an interface for simple queries on one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistent's interface is very simple and often insufficient to implement even slightly complex SQL. [`Esqueleto`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto) is a library building atop Persistent's database machinery which gives you a much more SQL-like Haskell DSL that may allow you to express what you're looking for.

Comment: I would gladly use Esqueleto. I am however bound to using only yesod in my current assignment. I see yesod provided a way to use raw SQL. Would you recommend using that?

Comment: That's possible, though I've never used the raw SQL capabilities of Persistent so I can't personally recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing the same assignment as I'm doing, I'd like to point you to the ManyToMany.hs file in the root of the starting framework.
It contains two key functions: joinTables and joinTables3, which will join tables based on given keys. An example on using the latter is given in /Handler/Payment.hs under getPaymentsR. Using that, you should be able to make a join such that the result is [(Entity ReceiptUser, Entity Receipt, Entity Payment)].

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured out how these worked so I pretty much finished the assignment now.